# How to concatenate sequences in the same multiFASTA files and then print result to a new FASTA file?

Tags: python, loops, sed, cat, fasta

I have a folder with over 50 FASTA files each with anywhere from 2-8 FASTA sequences within them, here's an example:

```
    testFOR.id_AH004930.fasta

>AH004930|2:1-128_Miopithecus_talapoin
ATGA
>AH004930|2:237-401_Miopithecus_talapoin
GGGT
>AH004930|2:502-580_Miopithecus_talapoin
CTTTGCT
>AH004930|2:681-747_Miopithecus_talapoin
GGTG

    testFOR.id_M95099.fasta

>M95099|1:1-90_Homo_sapien
TCTTTGC
>M95099|1:100-243_Homo_sapien
ATGGTCTTTGAA
```

They're all grouped based on their ID number (in this case AH004930 and M95099), which I've managed to extract from the original raw multiFASTA file using the very handy seqkit code found [HERE](https://www.biostars.org/p/332853).

What I am aiming to do is:

1. Use `cat` to put these sequences together within the file like this:

```
>AH004930|2:1-128_Miopithecus_talapoin
ATGAGGGTCTTTGCTGGTG

>M95099|1:1-90_Homo_sapien
TCTTTGCATGGTCTTTGAA
```

(I'm not fussed about the nucleotide position, I'm fussed about the ID and species name!)

2. Print this result out into a new FASTA file.

Ideally I'd really like to have all of these 50 files condensed into 1 FASTA that I can then go ahead and filter/align:

```
    GENE_L.fasta

>AH004930|2:1-128_Miopithecus_talapoin
ATGAGGGTCTTTGCTGGTG
>M95099|1:1-90_Homo_sapien
TCTTTGCATGGTCTTTGAA
....
```

So far I have found a way to achieve what I want but only one file at a time (using this code: `cat myfile.fasta | sed -e '1!{/^>.*/d;}' | sed  ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n//2g' > output.fasta` which I've sadly lost the link for the credit for) but a lot of these file names are very similar, so it's inevitable that if I did it manually, I'd miss some/it would be way too slow.

I have tried to put this into a loop and it's *kind of* there! But what it does is it cats each FASTA file, put's it into a new one BUT only keeps the first header, leaving me with a massive stitched together sequence;

```
for FILE in *; do cat *.fasta| sed -e '1!{/^>.*/d;}'| sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n//2g' > output.fasta; done
 

    output.fasta

>AH004930|2:1-128_Miopithecus_talapoin
ATGAGGGTCTTTGCTGGTGTCTTTGCATGGTCTTTGAAGGTCTTTGAAATGAGTGGT...
```

I wondered if making a loop similar to the one [HERE](https://www.biostars.org/p/105388/) would be any good but I am really unsure how to get it to print each header once it opens a new file.

How can I cat these sequences, print them into a new file and still keep these headers?
I would really appreciate any advice on where I've gone wrong in the loop and any solutions suitable for a zsh shell! I'm open to any python or linux solution. Thank you kindly in advance

Comment: Your question would be clearer to those of us who know Unix text tools but not a lot of bioinformatics if you could explain in more detail how the expected output is formed from these inputs.

Comment: @tripleee that's a great point, I think i've got the solution to it now (kindly supplied by user @potong) but it would be good to maybe explain it a bit more. I'll update my question accordingly for those who come across it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -s '1h;/>/d;H;$!d;x;s/\n//2g' file1 file2 file3 ...
```

Set `-s` to treat each file separately.

Copy the first line.

Delete any other lines containing `>`.

Append all other lines to the first.

Delete these lines except for the last.

At the end of the file, swap to the copies and remove all newlines except the first.

Repeat for all files.

---

Alternative for non-GNU seds:

```
for file in *.fasta; do sed '1h;/>/d;H;$!d;x;s/\n//2g' "$file"; done
```

N.B. MacOS sed may need to be put into a script and invoked using the `-f` option or split into several pieces using the `-e` option (less the `;` commands), your luck may vary.

Or perhaps:

```
for file in file?; do sed $'1h;/>/d;H;$!d;x;s/\\n/@/;s/\\n//g;s/@/\\n/' "$file"; done
```

Comment: Thank you for this but I am on a Mac OS and cannot use GNU sed - I will see if I can find the option for Mac and then give this a go. May I check, would putting ```*.fasta``` at the end of the code work instead of putting each file individually?

Comment: @Fitzy yes `*` is a wildcard for any name. As to the `-s` option, you could invoke sed within a for loop, see edit.

Comment: I had to remove the g from the non-GNU sed option (it came up with ```sed: 1: "1h;/>/d;H;$!d;x;s/\n//2g": more than one number or 'g' in substitute flags``` ) but once I had done that it does look like it's done the job! I will confirm and upvote this answer but would just like to check with you about the issue with the global command first. Thank you so much for your help, you are a star!

Comment: @Fitzy the `g` flag means global, so removing it will only replace the 2nd newline. I forgot that this is a GNU sed only feature. Another way around this is replace the first newline with something that can not exist in the record (perhaps `@`) then globally replace all newlines and finally replace the `@` by a newline. However I seem to remember that `\n` is not accepted by MacOS sed too. So you will need to insert a newline literally. HTH

Comment: thanks for your response. Going over the output and comparing manually to my results, it's is all checking out. I am seeing that the second line of each fasta (so first line of sequence) runs a lot longer and then the rest of the sequence is confined to the expected 80 characters. To check I've understood you, would that mean adding an ```@``` on the header line and then remove it after using your sed code? Thank you so much for your patience!

Comment: @Fitzy see final edit

Comment: Thank you potong, you are a star and I really appreciate all your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand exactly your issue, but if you simply want to concatenate contents from many files to a single file I believe the (Python) code below should work:

```
import os

input_folder = 'path/to/your/folder/with/fasta/files'
output_file = 'output.fasta'

with open(output_file, 'w') as outfile:
    for file_name in os.listdir(input_folder):
        if not file_name.endswith('.fasta'):  # ignore this
            continue
        file_path = os.path.join(input_folder, file_name)
        with open(file_path, 'r') as inpfile:
            outfile.write(inpfile.read())
```

Comment: Thank you kindly for this solution but it doesn't exactly do what I'm after. It does keep all the headers intact and put them into a new fasta file which is great but it does not cat the sequences inside each file together.